# Android: limit fragments loading with a viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have 3 fragments that are managed by an FragmentPagerAdapter, set to a viewPager.

I want to load fragments one by one, but when  the onCreate method of FragmentActivity is executed, the 2 first fragments are executed (onCreateView method).

I have tried to limit fragments loading with the setOffscreenPageLimit method but nothing change.

```
mPagerAdapter =  new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.tabviewpager);
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
```

Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The minimum for `OffscreenPageLimit` is set to `1` in the `ViewPager` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29):

```
private static final int DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES = 1;
....
public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) {
    if (limit < DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Requested offscreen page limit " + limit + " too small; defaulting to " +
                DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES);
        limit = DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES;
    }
    if (limit != mOffscreenPageLimit) {
        mOffscreenPageLimit = limit;
        populate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there another way to achieve that without using setOffscreenPageLimit ?

Comment: Do the fragments really need to be loaded one by one? If so, you might want to use something other than a `ViewPager` with an `Adapter`.  If you really want a `ViewPager` you could use an [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) on the ViewPager and wait til the `Fragment` is visible to do whatever you need.  You would just have to have do to some basic initialization in the `onCreateView` and then do the intensive work when the `Fragment` becomes visible.

Comment: Thank you for your precious help ! I ll try with  OnPageChangeListener.